# How can I refresh a list of images in a partialview when one of the images is clicked?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I have a partial view contained on a webpage that loads a number of thumbnail images in a set order. When a thumbnail is clicked I want to reload the list with the clicked thumbnail becoming the first image followed by the rest of the list in order, without reloading the rest of the webpage.

My PartialView contains the following code which loads the thumbnails and assigns each an `Url.Action`.

```
<% foreach (var image in (ImageModel)ViewData.Model) { %>
    <a href='<%= Url.Action("ImageList", "ImageView", new { imageFolderName = image.Folder, imageFile = ImageHelper.GetImageName(image.Path) }, null) %>'>
    <img src="/images/<%= image.Path %>" height="<%=(image.Height/4).ToString() %>" width="<%=(image.Width/4).ToString() %>" alt=""  /></a>
<% }%>
```

My controller has an `ActionResult` for initially loading the partial view when the containing page is loaded. I also included a method returning `PartialViewResult`.

public class ImageViewController : Controller

```
    public ActionResult ImageView(string imageFolderName, string imageFile)
    {
        return View(new ImageModel(imageFolderName, imageFile));
    }

    public PartialViewResult ImageList(string imageFolderName, string imageFile)
    {
        return PartialView(new ImageModel(imageFolderName, imageFile));
    }
```

If I set the `Url.Action` to ("ImageList", "ImageList"... the thumbnails are refreshed exactly the way I want, but the whole page is refreshed instead of just the partial view.

When I set `Url.Action` to ("ImageList", "ImageView"... instead of the partial view of the containing page getting refreshed, the containing page is gone and the partial page is loaded without it. That is, I see all my thumbnails in the correct order on a blank white web page.

I'm a noob and I haven't been able to make sense of any jQuery or Ajax Q and A about PartialViews in a way that it would apply to this scenario.

What good is a controller method that returns PartialView if it loads a new webpage instead of just refreshing the partial view within its containing page?

And, is there any documentation or explanation that show how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Links in general cause the whole page to refresh, you'll need to use ajax to refresh only part of the page.

I would go about doing the following:

This would be almost the same code, changes here is that it calls your original `ImageView` action. And I added a css class called `image`. Also I added a `div` surrounding the images (probably you already have that) and called it `allmypics`

```
<div id="allmypics">
<% foreach (var image in (ImageModel)ViewData.Model) { %>
    <a class="image" href='<%= Url.Action("ImageView", "ImageView", new { imageFolderName = image.Folder, imageFile = ImageHelper.GetImageName(image.Path) }, null) %>'>
    <img src="/images/<%= image.Path %>" height="<%=(image.Height/4).ToString() %>" width="<%=(image.Width/4).ToString() %>" alt=""  /></a>
<% }%>
</div>
```

Now you'll have to use some jQuery to hook up the click event.

```
<script type="javascript">
    //use the live method to listen to future clicks
    $('a.image').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent following the link
        $('#allmypics').load($(this).attr('href')); // load the result of the link into the 'allmypics' element. Use the href attribute of the link as address.
    } );
</script>
```

I added comments for you to understand.

Now we only have to change the `action`:

```
public ActionResult ImageView(string imageFolderName, string imageFile)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView(new ImageModel(imageFolderName, imageFile));
    else
        return View(new ImageModel(imageFolderName, imageFile));
}
```

The controller knows if it is an ajax request, so if it is, we return the partial view (don't forget to rename `ImageList.ascx` to `Imageview.ascx`), otherwise we return the whole page.

Now this will also work if the browser doesn't support javascript (it would just follow the link normally)

I didn't test it so there might be some syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gidon. A couple problems still. First is if the View and the Partial View have the same name, even with the differing extensions the call <%Html.RenderPartial("ImageView"); %> will throw a stack overflow exception. So I reverted back to the ImageList name for the partial view with the controller PartialViewResult ImageList.

Comment: continued
I added the jQuery script and have the images in the div with the correct ID, and the images with the class="image". I can see what it is attempting to do. But when I put a breakpoint in the controller and click on an image the Request.IsAjaxRequest function returns false.

I think what you suggested is close to what I need. I bought a jQuery book to get a better understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is a partial view does not help in this circumstance. When all I want to do is rotate a list of thumbnails all I need to do is append the top thumbnail to the bottom of the container using jQuery, and continue to do that until the clicked on thumbnail is at the top.

In my view I load the thumbnails when the page is first loaded.

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <% foreach (var image in (ImageModel)ViewData.Model) { %>
        <img src="/images/<%= image.Path %>" class="thumbnail" height="<%=(image.Height/4).ToString() %>" width="<%=(image.Width/4).ToString() %>" alt=""  />
    <% }%>

</div>
```

then I found the jQuery code to rotate the thumbnails that worked to be

```
$('.thumbnail').live('click', function() {

var imageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
var n = 0;

$('img.thumbnail').each(function(n) {
    if ((imageSrc == $(this).attr('src')) && (n == 0)) {
        $('div#thumbnails').append(this);
        return false;
    }
    if (imageSrc == $(this).attr('src')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('div#thumbnails').append(this);
    }
    n++;
});
```

This simply cuts the top thumbnail from the div and appends it to the bottom using a loop that stops when the clicked on thumbnail is reached, leaving the clicked on thumbnail as the top thumbnail.

The first if statement checks to see if the clicked thumbnail is the first thumbnail in the list, and if it is rotates the thumbnails by 1. In effect clicking on the first or second thumbnails in the list both moves the list by one. Clicking on any other thumbnail in the list makes that the first thumbnail and rotates accordingly.